# Calculate 38 days from month last date in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

let us consider date as

```
invoice.created_at = datetime.date(2021, 11, 17)
```

next_month_first_date here is getting the nextmonth first date

```
next_month_first_date = (invoice.created_at.replace(day=1) + datetime.timedelta(days=32)).replace(day=1)  
# datetime.date(2021, 12, 1)
```

Now I need last day of `invoice.created_at` month

```
this_month_last_day = ?
```

how to find last date of `invoice.created_at` month i.e `30/11/2021` and calculate 38 days from `this_month_last_day`? 38 days from this_month_last_day is `7/01/2022`

Comment: @OP - You incorrectly mentioned that 38 days from `this_month_last_day` is "7/01/2021". I changed this to "7/01/2022". Please check if that is what you intended to have.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the 1st day of the next month you can simply subtract 1 day from this to get the last day of the current month:

```
this_month_last_day = next_month_first_date - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
>>> this_month_last_day + datetime.timedelta(days=38)
datetime.date(2022, 1, 7)
```

Comment: ValidationError: [u"'' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]
  Receiving this error when trying to in this way

Comment: Huh? If the `next_month_first_date` is what you mentioned, this throws no errors. Not sure what you are doing wrong and which line is causing this error. Some dates in your `invoice` might be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's calender module to get the last day of the month

```py
import calendar
import datetime

created_at = datetime.date(2021, 11, 17)
last_day_as_int = calendar.monthrange(created_at.year, created_at.month)[1] # 30
last_day_as_date = created_at.replace(day=last_day_as_int) # datetime.date(2021, 11, 30)
target_date = last_day_as_date + datetime.timedelta(days=38) # datetime.date(2022, 1, 7)
```